# Get rid of Duplicates in SQL Report Drop down Parameter (SharePoint Report embedded)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, sql

Is it possible to have a drop down parameter only show a unique value if I have multiple values? If I have 5 items with 123, I only want 123 to show up once in the drop down.

Currently I have a DataSet with one field showing `Job_Number`. I have the Parameter `@JobNumber` looking at that field but it is showing multiple items in the drop down with the same values. I tried adding filters but got errors saying:

> Forward dependencies are not valid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and just FYI this is for a SharePoint list I'm running the data on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out see link below if anyone else is running into this issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/04/28/walkthrough-how-to-get-distinct-values-of-a-column-of-a-sharepoint-list-using-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx